# Can you render Adobe Premiere or After Effects projects on Linux using a render manager?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, linux

*I'm looking for a way to render Premiere or Edius projects on linux via command line.*

As you may know, there are a lot of render managers like *Deadline*, *Render Pal* or *Smedge* in order to build a custom render farm for all kind of creative applications or 3d renderers.

These render managers mostly support all of the major platforms (Windows, OSX and Linux), but film editing software like Adobe Premiere (along with After Effects) or Edius don't support linux OS at all.

Can I use a render manager to render a Premiere, After Effetcts or even a Edius project on Linux?

Comment: My answer adresses your render manager issue... it has nothing to do with your idea of using a frame server.

Answer (score 3):

No. Unfortunately Adobe only supports win or osx. Official [forum post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/569519) about [Deadline:](http://www.thinkboxsoftware.com/deadline/)

> Deadline itself is a cross-platform application, but it can only render on  operating systems that the rendering software itself supports. So AE and  C4D will only work on Windows and OSX.

Also see the manual: http://docs.thinkboxsoftware.com/products/deadline/7.1/1_User%20Manual/

---

Thus it depends on the **main application**, if you are able to build a render farm on linux. In the case of adobe, the only remaining option is using a [Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) for now.